# How and when to set JSS editing secret on Sitecore CM?

Tags: jss, azure, presentation

I'm building the `JSS` app from the `dotnet nextjs` template and it is working on my local with `XP1 topology`. However, I have difficulties deploying the app to our Sitecore installation which is deployed on Azure (with Sitecore CMS). I have set up one app service to run our rendering server: the primary app service will run the rendering server pointing to CD, and one slot to run the rendering server pointing to CM.

The question goes, how and when do I set the editing secret? From the container, it is set as environment variables. Do I set this on file `App_Config/Sitecore/JavascriptServices/Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.config`? This would mean sharing the same editing secret for all sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a patch file called `App.JssEditing.config` and add editing secrets like this for all the environments.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
    <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or XMCloud" security:require="Sitecore">
        <settings>
            <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="<your-value>"  env:require="Development" />
            <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="<your-value>"  env:require="Dev" />
            <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="<your-value>"  env:require="Qa" />
            <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="<your-value>"  env:require="Prod" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

While working with docker, you can keep this file in your docker deploy folder and it will be replaced in your Sitecore instance.

Hope this helps.